# OpenID Connect + OKTA

Tags: react-native, openid-connect, okta, appauth

I just set up our first OpenID connect apps in Okta, and assigned users don't see the app in the dashboard (though they are authenticating just fine) can  i know why??. will openid app appear in the dashboard of okta.
can any one help me.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set Login Initiated By to 'Either Okta or App' in the General Settings of the application and enable 'Display application icon to users' in the Application Visibility